# Does Button.click() stop script execution?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have some code that I paste into the browser that clicks several buttons. After the first one it stops, but if I keep pressing enter in the address bar it eventually clicks them all but it only works one by one.

Does `Button.click()` stop script execution?

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); 
for(var i in buttons) 
{
   if(buttons[i].getAttribute("title") == "Get Car Quote") 
   {
      buttons[i].click();
   }
}
```

Comment: pls explain more abt your need.

Comment: It works fine with me: http://jsfiddle.net/gidon/yb64a/ (tested IE9, Chrome 9)

Comment: What does the HTML that this script is running on look like?

Comment: The HTML is a list of <button> elements with various titles. I am interested in the titles that are labeleb "Get Car Quotes". It's supposed to loop through all the buttoms and click them, but it will click one, and stop. I have to keep pressing enter when pasting it into the address bar to have it click them 1 by 1.

Comment: If I replace the click method with alert(buttons[i].getAttribute("title")) I can see it's looping. So I can't understand why button.click stops after the first.

Comment: what does the button do anyway? it could be that it's clicked but the result of the click prevents another click to produce its result